# Using geometry nodes to Snap / move two vertex points from different objects together

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes to snap / move two vertex points from different objects together.

I can get the vector of the index of the two vertex points on the objects I want to move which is at index **224** and **216**

1st) Static object:

[image: img 1]

2nd) Object to move:

[image: img2]

It should look something like this:
**(yes I know I can translate the object using a transform node but snapping objects together using their index is much more powerful and exact)**

[image: img 3]

I subtract the vectors from each other but the two objects don't snap together or display correctly.

**My logic:**

1. Get vector of vertex of static object
2. Get vector of vertex of object to move
3. Minus the vectors of the vertex then move the object.

[image: img4]

See attached file.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do here, but your question should be solved with the following answer:

[image]

Get the two positions of the desired points with `Transfer Attribute` and plug the integer directly there.

Then calculate the direction vector between the two positions and use this vector as offset in the node `Set Position`.

If you have the correct direction vector and do not move all points to a single position, all points will be moved evenly with the given vector.

*...Also, you would have to swap the values for the index (just a guess).*

Comment: Thanks looks like I was overthinking it a bit and had some connections wrong / extra connections not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Logic's OK. If you don't want all the points to go to the same place, you're offsetting them, rather than setting their position:

[image]

Here with the star modified, source index 4, and target index 29:

[image]