# Snapping specific vertices together from two different objects using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Snapping specific vertices together from two different objects using geometry nodes.

**Example:**
I have two separate objects and I would like to snap **specific** vertices together.

Snap secondary object vertex **0** to pyramid vertex **3** and
secondary vertex **1** to pyramid vertex **1**

Please note this is a simple test object the geometries will be more complex.

[image: img1]

Secondary object:

[image: img2]

I get

[image: img3]

I did look at [Using geometry nodes to Snap / move two vertex points from different objects together](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272416/using-geometry-nodes-to-snap-move-two-vertex-points-from-different-objects-tog) but the **secondary object (line) should be stretched vertex to vertex.**

I'm trying to get something to look like this after the vertices have been snapped together.  **This will be used for dynamic measurements of distances and angles between different non-connecting vertices**.

[image: img look]

Node group
[image: look]

Attached Blend file

[image]

Comment: i honestly don't understand why the linked question doesn't help you here...maybe provide a blend file, so we can see what you did wrong?

Comment: @Chris I've attached the blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this node tree should do what you want:

[image]

result:

[image]

Important: if you are using a set position without (!) connecting the select input, you will change every position of that geometry.